# How to find password on a router (cabled) without a hard reset? brute-force only option?

Tags: networking, router, passwords, administrator, brute-force

So I've seen a few post like that on here but none seem to work in my case short of brute-forcing but I've never done it before so I want to be sure of what I'm doing first.

Alright here is the deal, moved into a new flat where there is a **DASAN Networks H640GW**. Until there, all is fine. However the settings on the router are stupid! *(LAN lines going in the walls limited to 10MBps (rate limited) when there is around 150MBps in total, WIFI off,...)* I have tried the basic combination (user/user) but no luck. Contacted my ISP which informed me that they are "the only ones managing the router" and therefore cannot give me the password but can send someone over to do my changes in around 25working days....

Quite frankly, working a 10% of my internet speed for the next 5weeks and only accessing over lan unless I go and buy an access point... just not my cup of tea.

The router takes care of my broadband, landline, my TV (over IP) and is connected via fiber so hard reset is out of the question. Too many settings that I can't afford to change.

As far as I can think Brute-forcing it is my only option...

was going to post pictures of the login but instead here are links (su.com wont let me.. :D)

[image]

When a wrong password is entered it gives a HTTP pop up.

[image]

Any ideas other than a brute-force attack?
If not, any tutorials for this kind of brute force attack or tips?

Comment: If you don't know the password then your only option is a brute force attack.  If you have a serial connection it would be relatively easy since you could perform the attack over SSH.

Comment: What makes you think that a hard reset would break everything else. The defaults are likely to have already been set by the ISP, for precisely this type of occurrence. [unless the ISP didn't provide the router]

Comment: I would be fairly confident that the password is long and obscure.  Brute force might work if you have a few years.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but the admin password for the H640GW is "vertex25".

Just incase someone is still looking for this.

Cheers!
Jaspal

Answer (score -2):

Try this combination:

**User** : `admin`

**Password**: `tiOvc387D9nb`

it worked for me using that device.